# Spring Batch executing job twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created a simple batch application with Spring Boot that reads the data from the database and sends the fetched items as a list to a REST API. Everything is working fine but it is sending the data to REST API twice. I checked for answers on other posts. Tried **spring.batch.job.enabled=false**.

The batch configuration class is as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }

    @Bean
    //@StepScope
    public ItemReader<ModelClass> modelItemReader() {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<ModelClass> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<ModelClass>();
        final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean =
                new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause(SQLQueries.SELECT_QUERY);
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause(SQLQueries.FROM_CLAUSE);
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey(SQLQueries.SORT_KEY);
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause(SQLQueries.WHERE_CONDITION);
        try {
            reader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setPageSize(100);
        reader.setRowMapper(new ModelClassRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelClassItemWriter modelClassItemWriter(){
        return new ModelClassItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step fetchDataStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("fetchDataStep")
                .<ModelClass, ModelClass> chunk(50)
                .reader(modelItemReader())
                .writer(modelClassItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job fetchDataJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("fetchDatatJob")
                .start(fetchDataStep())
                .build();
    }
}
```

The itemwriter class is as follows -

```
public class ModelClassItemWriter implements ItemWriter<ModelClass> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ModelClassItemWriter .class);

    @Value("${rest.uri}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends ModelClass> items) throws Exception {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<List<? extends ModelClass>> request =
                new HttpEntity<List<? extends ModelClass>>(items, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
        LOGGER.info("**********RESPONSE************" + result.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Here, it is sending data twice to this REST API. The batch needs to be executed every 10 minutes. I have written a scheduler that runs this job every 10 minutes. Following are the logs that shows that it is executing twice.

```
2021-05-14 20:50:00.070  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [fetchDataStep]
2021-05-14 20:50:32.833  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [fetchDataStep] executed in 32s763ms
2021-05-14 20:50:32.837  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=fetchDatatJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{JobID=1621005600052}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 32s775ms
2021-05-14 20:50:33.017  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=fetchDatatJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1621005633015}]
2021-05-14 20:50:33.021  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [fetchDataStep]
2021-05-14 20:51:02.712  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [fetchDataStep] executed in 29s691ms
2021-05-14 20:51:02.716  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=fetchDatatJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{JobID=1621005633015}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 29s696ms
2021-05-14 21:00:00.061  INFO 84100 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=fetchDatatJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1621006200051}]
```

The scheduler code is as follows -

```
@Component
public class ScheduleBatchJobs {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @Scheduled(cron = "* */10 * * * ?")
    public void perform() throws Exception
    {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();

        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please support me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in the scheduler. Is the scheduler launching the job twice?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I have updated the question with the scheduler code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spring-batch configuration looks good. The problem is with the cron expression.

This cron expression `cron = "* */10 * * * ?"` will execute after every 10 minutes and it will keep triggering the method every time the thread completes the job with in one minute. For example:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* */5 * * * ?")
    public void print() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Hello: "+ Instant.now());
    }
```

In this case the print() will be executed after every five minutes. But, the thread completes in 10s, so after 10s it will trigger the print() another time and this print() will keep getting invoked for another one minute. Below is the log:

```
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:25:10.013Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:25:21.005Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:25:32.001Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:25:43.002Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:25:54.005Z

Hello: 2021-05-15T15:30:10.009Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:30:21.001Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:30:32.002Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:30:43.001Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:30:54.005Z
Hello: 2021-05-15T15:31:05.002Z
```

In your case the job completes in 30 seconds, so the cron expression triggers the perform() another time as it is with in the timeframe of 1 minute.
Please change your cron expression to

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 * * * ?")
```

This will trigger the perform() only once after every 10 minutes even the job completes with in 1 minute timeframe.

Comment: Hello Rahul, it did work. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @thelearner, additionally you can use pages like https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html to see the next execution dates of cron expressions. If you put your original cron expression you will see what is explained in this answer.

Comment: @thelearner, you're welcome. Please accept and upvote this answer as I believe it helped you and may help others in this community.  Additionally, this will help me to grow in this community. Thank you!

Comment: @HernánAlarcón, thank you for sharing the link here. Your comment is really helpful.

Comment: Hello @HernánAlarcón/@RahulDey,  Sorry for bothering you guys again, but I am facing the same issue. The catch is (which is kinda weird) that it sometimes execute twice and sometimes it just runs fine. I also checked the link shared by Hernan, it shows the same execution time for **0/10** as well as ** */10 **. Can you please help me in resolving this?

Comment: For this expression * */10 * * * ?, below is the next executions:
Tue May 18 16:00:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:01 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:02 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:03 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:04 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:05 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:06 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:00:07 UTC 2021

Comment: For this expression  0 0/10 * * * ?, here is the execution list:
Tue May 18 16:00:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:10:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:20:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:30:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:40:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 16:50:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 17:00:00 UTC 2021
Tue May 18 17:10:00 UTC 2021

Comment: Its not same, I have tested it locally several times. Are you sure you're using "0 0/10 * * * ?"